# SQL Output text or date depending on another field

Tags: sql, casting, case

I have a date field that sometimes I want to print a message instead of a date depending on the value in another field.  I tried this:

`select`
        CASE
`WHEN isExofficio = 1`
            THEN CAST ('Never Expires' as varchar(20))
`ELSE boardDate`
        END
    from tableName

I know this won't work as is, but this is what I'm trying to do - output a message if isExofficio = 1; otherwise output the date.  Any ideas? (Sorry, I still can't seem to get the formatting right!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In either case it has to return the same data type result, so you can just convert the date to varchar, so try this way.

```
select
CASE WHEN isExofficio = 1
THEN CAST 'Never Expires' ELSE CONVERT(varchar,boardDate,101)
END from tableName
```

Comment: Thanks - I knew it was easy for you more experienced SQL geeks!  I had that thought but didn't act on it!

Comment: if it answers your question, then please accept it as answer